# Foundation abide 5.5 ajax submit duplicated

Tags: zurb-foundation

On 5.4 it works, but on 5.5 there are two requests

```
 $('#sendSms form').on('valid.fndtn.abide', function () {
            $('#sendSms button').disable(true);
            $.post(app.dir + '/sms', $('#sendSms form').serialize(), function (data) {
                               $('#sendSms button').disable(false);
                },
             'json' // I expect a JSON response
            );
        });


<div id="sendSms" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
    <h2>Send sms</h2>

    <form data-abide="ajax">
        <div class="SmsMessage-field">
            <label>
                Body <small>required</small>
                <input type="text" maxlength="300" required name="SmsMessage" id="SmsMessage" />
            </label>
            <small class="error"></small>
        </div>
        <div class="SmsPhoneNo-field">
            <label>
                PhoneNo <small>required</small>
                <input name="SmsPhoneNo" type="text" pattern="\d{9}" maxlength="9" required>
            </label>
            <small class="error"></small>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>

    <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work around this issue by listening to the `valid` event instead of the `valid.fndtn.abide` event.

I have a comment on the [project's github issue page](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/5392) explaining whats the cause of this issue, but here is the copy.

I believe this issue is cause because of the way [jQuery's event](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names) namespacing works. Basically, triggering a `valid` event will fire any listener listening to `valid.*` events.

Because Foundation is deprecating the `valid` event and moving to the `valid.fndtn.abide` event, the current version of the code triggers both during validation, but because of the way jQuery's event works, listener for `valid.fndtn.abide` will fire for both `valid` and `valid.fndtn.abide` event, and since both events fired, the listener ran twice, each for both event.

The obvious solution is to simply trigger the old events during validation, and I actually have prepared a PR with this fix, but I'm not sure what the developer's intentions are, since I noticed they are triggering both versions of the events in other places as well.

Answer (score 0):

As stated on the Github issue page, use this quick fix;

```
$('form').on('valid.fndtn.abide', function(e) {
    // Fix for valid event firing twice
    if(e.namespace != 'abide.fndtn')  return;

    // The rest of your form handling code here...
```

Answer (score 0):

I know by this time you already solved your problem but let me just share what I did.
I have a same problem with yours a year ago and I tried this:

```
$(document).on('valid.fndtn.abide','.myForm', Foundation.utils.debounce(function(e) {// Handle Click 


    //ajax function here
      console.log('I am not fired twice');

    //clear all fields for re-validation after successful submission  


}, 1000, true));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Foundation 6 but the principle shoule be the same for 5.5 !

I think the problem is that '**valid**.fndtn.abide' fires for every validated input in the form.

What I did was to add to the "Foundation.Abide.prototype.validateForm" function to emit a new trigger '**validform**.fndtn.abide' that is emitted when the whole form validates.

I then watch this new trigger and run my ajax call when this new trigger fires:

```
window.onload = function() {


  // Overwrite Foundation Abide validateForm to emit a trigger 'validform.fndtn.abide' when the form validates
  Foundation.Abide.prototype.validateForm = function($form) {
    var self = this,
        inputs = $form.find('input'),
        inputCount = $form.find('input').length,
        counter = 0;

    while (counter < inputCount) {
      self.validateInput($(inputs[counter]), $form);
      counter++;
    }

    // what are all the things that can go wrong with a form?
    if ($form.find('.form-error.is-visible').length || $form.find('.is-invalid-label').length) {
      $form.find('[data-abide-error]').css('display', 'block');
      $form.trigger('invalidform.fndtn.abide', $form); // <== Added trigger
    }
    else {
      $form.find('[data-abide-error]').css('display', 'none');
      $form.trigger('validform.fndtn.abide', $form); // <== Added trigger
    }
  }


  // Listen for 'validform.fndtn.abide'
  $('#diventare_cliente_form').on('validform.fndtn.abide', function(e) { 

      var formdata =  $(this).serialize();

      $.ajax({
        url: '/backend/email_handler.php',
        data: formdata,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        type: "post"
      })
      .done(function(json) {
        // do something
      })
      .fail(function() {
        // do something
      })

  });

};
```

Hope this helps someone because I blew a whole day trying various solutions and this was the cleanest I found. Maybe I'm missing something here regarding Abide and Ajax calls but it seems strange that the Foundation Team didn't provide a way to catch when the whole form validates !